# Syntax error with my "if statement"

Tags: php, syntax-error

How do I write this if statement correctly so that the "||" works?  || represents "or" by the way.  When i take out "|| >30" I receive no syntax error.  But when I do include "|| >30" I receive a syntax error saying that ">" is unexpected.

```
if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 7 || >30){
            $errors[] = 'Your password must be 7 to 30 characters long.'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 7 || >30){
```

should be this I presume:

```
if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 7 || strlen($_POST['password']) > 30){
```

Since you asked for a shorter version of this this is the simplest way using the same logic and functions:

```
$length = strlen($_POST['password']);
if ($length < 7 || $length > 30){
```

Comment: I think OP know that and he want to shorten the statement.

Comment: Awesome that worked, it says I have to wait 11 minutes before I can accept the answer so I'll make sure to do so.
Thank you!

Comment: I'm a beginner so I actually didn't know that, but if there is a way to shorten the statement feel free to post it.  I don't mind learning shortcuts :)

Comment: @KacyRaye, You welcome. Btw, you should never limit the length of a password as that is a bad security practice. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/98768/1592648

Comment: Looks like I'll be removing the max length then lol...

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to make it easier is to store your password length in a variable like this:

```
 $pwd_len = strlen($_POST['password'])

 if ($pwd_len < 7 || $pwd_len > 30){
```

This maybe not useful in your case but will be helpful when you need to refer to your password length many times. So it will save you a lot of time instead of always write `strlen($_POST['password'])`

Maybe I'm wrong but hope it helps :)

Comment: No you're totally right, thanks I'll keep variables in mind when writing code from now on.
I just started like a week ago so I need all the tips I can get :P