# python script to accept 8 char password with these conditions only: 2 num, 2 upper, 2 lower, and 2 special

Tags: python, regex, if-statement, passwords

This is what I've done till now. And when it goes wrong it doesn't print 'Not Okay'. I'm still not able to figure out how to check special chars.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def passw_check():
    passin = raw_input("Enter the password")

    if len(passin) == 8:       # checking total length of password
        if sum(map(str.isupper, passin))== 2: #check 2 upper chars
            if sum(map(str.islower, passin))== 2:  #check 2 lower chars
                if sum(map(str.isdigit, passin))== 4:  #check 2 digits chars
                    print 'Passwords Okay'
                else: 
                    print 'Not Okay!'

passw_check()
```

Comment: Well, your else is only associated with your final IF. You need to be clear in your question whether you have two problems or one.

Comment: Then, should it be in indented with first IF, because/if they are nested? Yes you are right my if-else loop is not working correctly.

Comment: I hope you're [not actually trying to apply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98768/should-i-impose-a-maximum-length-on-passwords) those [password restrictions](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33470/what-technical-reasons-are-there-to-have-low-maximum-password-lengths) on a real public system.

Comment: @llmari karonen, It will only make things safer on internet, isn't it? Not really, its for my personal script only! hey!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import string

def validate(s):
    def is_punc(c): return c in string.punctuation
    if len(s) != 8:                   return False
    if sum(map(str.isupper, s)) != 2: return False
    if sum(map(str.islower, s)) != 2: return False
    if sum(map(str.isdigit, s)) != 2: return False
    if sum(map(is_punc, s))     != 2: return False
    # Note of the tests have been violated, return True
    return True


def passw_check():
    passin = raw_input("Enter the password: ")

    if validate(passin):
        print 'Passwords Okay'
    else:
        print 'Not Okay!'

passw_check()
```

Here, the `validate` function is very clear and the logic is easy to understand.

Also note, you say you only want 2 numeric characters, but the test in your code checks for 4.  I changed this to 2 to fit your problem description, just a heads up.

*Edit* Added `string.punctuation` test instead of just assuming the non-alphanum characters are "special" -- this may be unnecessary/undesired if you want to accept things like whitespace / don't want to depend on the system's locale.

Comment: This give error in script:Enter the password: UI((98kk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 22, in <module>
    passw_check()
  File "new.py", line 17, in passw_check
    if validate(passin):
  File "new.py", line 10, in validate
    if sum(map(is_punc, s))     != 2: return False
  File "new.py", line 5, in is_punc
    def is_punc(c): return c in string.punctuation
NameError: global name 'string' is not defined

Comment: @sunnyp. a previous edit of the answer omitted the `import string` at the top, try it again with that line.

Comment: yep it was 'import string' that was missing. Now working perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Only the innermost `if` has an `else`-branch. Use `and` to check all conditions at once:

```
def passw_check():
    passin = raw_input("Enter the password")

    if (len(passin) == 8 and       # checking total length of password
        sum(map(str.isupper, passin)) == 2 and #check 2 upper chars
        sum(map(str.islower, passin)) == 2 and  #check 2 lower chars
        sum(map(str.isdigit, passin))== 4):  #check 2 digits chars
        print 'Passwords Okay'
    else: 
        print 'Not Okay!'
    return passin

passw = passw_check()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex, this should validate that the `passin` has 2 lower, 2 upper, 2 digits and 2 specials (you can change:

```
import re, string
def passw_check(passin):
    lower = "(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z])"
    upper = "(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])"
    digit = "(?=.*[0-9].*[0-9])"
    special = "(?=.*[{0}].*[{0}])".format(re.escape(string.punctuation))
    return re.match("^.*{}{}{}{}.*$".format(lower, upper, digit, special), passin)

check = passw_check(raw_input("Enter the password"))
print("Password Okay" if check else "Not Okay!")
```