# Regex: How to create a pattern to match at least one lower case char, upper case char, digit, and at least one char between [$@#&!]

Tags: regex, html

These are the set of criteria that I need to fulfill:

- At least 1 letter between lowercase  [a - z]      ->  25%
- At least 1 letter between uppercase [A - Z]     ->  25%
- At least 1 number between [ 0 - 9 ]     -> 25%
- At least 1 character from [ $@#&! ]   -> 25%
- Minimum length of password is 6  and maximum length of password is 12

This is the pattern I used to try to fulfil these criteria.

I've not yet grasped how regular expressions work.

I've also not figured how to set a pattern to check for the fourth criteria [$@#&!].

```
   <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="enter your password" 
`pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[$@#&!]).{6,12}"required>
```

So I would need some assistance with this.

Comment: [Don't enforce a maximum password length.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98768/should-i-impose-a-maximum-length-on-passwords)

Comment: @Welbog ok I could use JavaScript to achieve that instead right. I've already sorted out this challenge in JavaScript. But I want to understand how to achieve this using the pattern attribute in HTML 5.

Comment: Did you try adding `(?=.*[$@#&!])` to your list of look-aheads?

Comment: @Welbog I've added it now. The problem is that I read that the * indicates 0 or more instead of 1 or more. So if I replace it with + through out the regex would that be more accurate?

Comment: The `pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[$@#&!]).{6,12}"` pattern is the one you should use as per your requirements. What answer do you expect if you have the answer in the question?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I read in one of the answers on this site that the .{6,12} is wrong because it indicates "between 6 to 12 times" as opposed to min 6 and max 12

Comment: You quantified `.`, so `.{6,12}` matches any char other than a line break char 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 or 12 times. See [**your regex demo with explanation**](https://regex101.com/r/ll4hAx/1).

Comment: Why are we still discussing the "max password length"? Don't do that. It's **bad** for security, and user friendliness.

Comment: @HemanthGowda This is why I asked the question because I keep getting different answers. Wictor told me that I already had the answer to the question.  I was hoping that he would at least explain how the (*) qualifies as "at least 1" instead of "0 or more which it actually means".

Comment: (?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[@#!*])(?=^.{6,7}$)(?=.*[0-9]) I tested this.. Works. I can explain if you specify what you're confused about exactly. The comment thread is a bit messy.

Comment: @HemanthGowda first the * means 0 or more not one or more. Secondly the ^ is negation or so I read. How does ^{6,7} achieve the range specified in the question.

Comment: @HemanthGowda Thanks for offering to explain. I need that badly.

Comment: Lets get one thing clear, ^ inside "[]" means a not, if its outside that, it means beginning of string. so ^.{6,7}$ means the whole string can contain 6-7 characters(Any kind cuz ".")

Comment: Yes, the * means zero or more. but in this scenario, we are using it to do a variable look ahead. Say (?=.*[a-z]), the .* here ensures that a "111a" matches and also a "a" matches. In "111a" the ".*" consumed the 111 and in the "a" case, .* matched for zero occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex pattern:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@#&!]).{6,12}$
```

---

**Note:** *Depends on the syntax and/or programming language you use, some of the special characters may need to be escaped by `\` prefix.*

Comment: What does the dollar sign at the end mean.

Comment: I tried using (?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@#&!]).{6,12}

Comment: And it worked. So that's why I want to know what the "^" and "$" do in front and behind the pattern.

Comment: In the pattern I tested now, the only difference between that and yours is the "^" and "$". That's what I'm trying to say.

Comment: $ means the end of string. If you don't use it in the place I specified, you wouldn't be enforcing the max length. (You'll get substring matches.) ^.{1,3} will match for "aaaaaa" but ^.{1,3}$ wouldn't. ^ means the beginning of string.

Comment: Exactly as @HemanthGowda said/wrote.

Comment: @user20490 - See https://regex101.com/r/Uqfe2b/1 and play with text and regex pattern. Remove `$` and you will see a difference.