# Password confirmation in TypeScript with `class-validator`

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-validator

Today, I am trying to figure out how to validate a Sign Up form in the backend side (NestJS) of the app. I am just wondering if exists a way to validate `password` and `passwordConfirm` matching, using `class-validator` package to build up a custom validator or exploit provided ones. I am thinking about a class validator, not a field one.

```
// Maybe validator here
export class SignUpDto {
    @IsString()
    @MinLength(4)
    @MaxLength(20)
    username: string;

    @IsString()
    @MinLength(4)
    @MaxLength(20)
    @Matches(/((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$/, {message: 'password too weak'})
    password: string;

    @IsString()
    @MinLength(4)
    @MaxLength(20)
    passwordConfirm: string;
}
```

What do you suggest?

Comment: Don't think it supports this yet: https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/issues/486

Comment: @AndreiTătar What a pity! Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @piero: It's not supported yet as mentioned. But here's an example decorator (@IsLongerThan): https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/tree/master/sample/sample6-custom-decorator .... it checks if a property is longer than another one. So it's possible to compare one property against another. You can use this example to create a decorator that does what you want.

Comment: @ChristopheGeers I will give it a try as soon as possible. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @ChristopheGeers thanks for your help! It worked!

Comment: @PieroMacaluso I would not set a maxlength on passwords, see: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98768/should-i-impose-a-maximum-length-on-passwords

i also hope you hash the passwords

Comment: @YAMM, you are right! It was just an example. By the way, I think that it could be better to set a very high max length to avoid problems with very large inputs (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/98857/7358319).

Comment: @PieroMacaluso ok thats a valid point... on the other hand if you use bcrypt... https://www.mscharhag.com/software-development/bcrypt-maximum-password-length

Comment: @YAMM Thanks for the link! Very interesting!

Comment: Late to the game but why even send the password confirmation to the service? The entire (somewhat misguided) reason for the password confirmation is to ensure that the user has entered the password they intended to. That validation can take place entirely on the UI-side and only one password property needs to be sent to the service.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve the password matching problem thanks to the suggestion of [@ChristopheGeers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893099/christophe-geers) in the comments of my question:

> @piero: It's not supported yet as mentioned. But here's an example decorator (@IsLongerThan): [LINK](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/tree/master/sample/sample6-custom-decorator) .... it checks if a property is longer than another one. So it's possible to compare one property against another. You can use this example to create a decorator that does what you want.

Here it is the solution I propose:

#### sign-up.dto.ts

```
export class SignUpDto {
    @IsString()
    @MinLength(4)
    @MaxLength(20)
    username: string;

    @IsString()
    @MinLength(4)
    @MaxLength(20)
    @Matches(/((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$/, {message: 'password too weak'})
    password: string;

    @IsString()
    @MinLength(4)
    @MaxLength(20)
    @Match('password')
    passwordConfirm: string;
}
```

#### match.decorator.ts

```
import {registerDecorator, ValidationArguments, ValidationOptions, ValidatorConstraint, ValidatorConstraintInterface} from 'class-validator';

export function Match(property: string, validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
    return (object: any, propertyName: string) => {
        registerDecorator({
            target: object.constructor,
            propertyName,
            options: validationOptions,
            constraints: [property],
            validator: MatchConstraint,
        });
    };
}

@ValidatorConstraint({name: 'Match'})
export class MatchConstraint implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {

    validate(value: any, args: ValidationArguments) {
        const [relatedPropertyName] = args.constraints;
        const relatedValue = (args.object as any)[relatedPropertyName];
        return value === relatedValue;
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems a very good solution, but it has a lot of problem with the _TypeScript_ linting.

Comment: You can add this method to MatchConstraint class for error message:
`defaultMessage(args: ValidationArguments){ return args.property + " must match " + args.constraints[0]; }`

Comment: But password is stored in db in hashed form, so there will be issues with validation. Take even length

Answer (score 12):

Here's an extended example which inlines the validator and provides a default message for it. This way you don't have to enter a message each time you use the `@IsEqualTo` decorator.

```
import { 
    registerDecorator, 
    ValidationArguments, 
    ValidationOptions 
} from 'class-validator';

export function IsEqualTo(property: string, validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
    return (object: any, propertyName: string) => {
      registerDecorator({
        name: 'isEqualTo',
        target: object.constructor,
        propertyName,
        constraints: [property],
        options: validationOptions,
        validator: {
          validate(value: any, args: ValidationArguments) {
          const [relatedPropertyName] = args.constraints;
          const relatedValue = (args.object as any)[relatedPropertyName];
          return value === relatedValue;
        },

        defaultMessage(args: ValidationArguments) {
          const [relatedPropertyName] = args.constraints;
          return `${propertyName} must match ${relatedPropertyName} exactly`;
        },
      },
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: nice....perfect solution

Answer (score 7):

For the validating password, I suggest using `@IsStrongPassword` from `class-validator`

It could be like this

```
 @IsStrongPassword({
    minLength: 8,
    minLowercase: 1,
    minNumbers: 1,
    minSymbols: 1,
    minUppercase: 1
  })
@IsStrongPassword
```

Comment: this should be the top answer right now

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is pretty good for me, but we could make a spelling mistake like:

```js
@Match('passwordd')
//
```

So I would like to make it more strict with `Generics`

```js
@Match(SignUpDto, (s) => s.password)
```

**match.decorator.ts**

```js
import { ClassConstructor } from "class-transformer";

export const Match = <T>(
  type: ClassConstructor<T>,
  property: (o: T) => any,
  validationOptions?: ValidationOptions,
) => {
  return (object: any, propertyName: string) => {
    registerDecorator({
      target: object.constructor,
      propertyName,
      options: validationOptions,
      constraints: [property],
      validator: MatchConstraint,
    });
  };
};

@ValidatorConstraint({ name: "Match" })
export class MatchConstraint implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  validate(value: any, args: ValidationArguments) {
    const [fn] = args.constraints;
    return fn(args.object) === value;
  }

  defaultMessage(args: ValidationArguments) {
    const [constraintProperty]: (() => any)[] = args.constraints;
    return `${constraintProperty} and ${args.property} does not match`;
  }
}
```

So we can use `Match` decorator like this:

```js
export class SignUpDto {
  // ...
  password: string;

  // finally, we have 
  @Match(SignUpDto, (s) => s.password)
  passwordConfirm: string;
}
```

Comment: Which module is `ClassConstructor` from? I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: You need to import it from class-transformer: `import { ClassConstructor } from "class-transformer"`;

Answer (score 3):

I like the approach of the IsEqualTo decorator, but I were also concerned about the typos when using a property that is not in my Dto, so I end up with this:

```
import {
  registerDecorator,
  ValidationArguments,
  ValidationOptions,
} from 'class-validator';

export function IsEqualTo<T>(
  property: keyof T,
  validationOptions?: ValidationOptions,
) {
  return (object: any, propertyName: string) => {
    registerDecorator({
      name: 'isEqualTo',
      target: object.constructor,
      propertyName,
      constraints: [property],
      options: validationOptions,
      validator: {
        validate(value: any, args: ValidationArguments) {
          const [relatedPropertyName] = args.constraints;
          const relatedValue = (args.object as any)[relatedPropertyName];
          return value === relatedValue;
        },

        defaultMessage(args: ValidationArguments) {
          const [relatedPropertyName] = args.constraints;
          return `${propertyName} must match ${relatedPropertyName} exactly`;
        },
      },
    });
  };
}
```

and use it like this:

```
export class CreateUserDto {
  @IsEqualTo<CreateUserDto>('password')
  readonly password_confirmation: string;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I like the accepted answer, but i think we can simplify the process by passing the property we want to validate against to, as a string in the constraints array.

example :

```
@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'CustomMatchPasswords', async: false })
export class CustomMatchPasswords implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
   validate(password: string, args: ValidationArguments) {

      if (password !== (args.object as any)[args.constraints[0]]) return false;
      return true;
   }

   defaultMessage(args: ValidationArguments) {
      return "Passwords do not match!";
   }
}
```

and then we can use the validator without the need to create a decorator:

```
    @IsString()
    @MinLength(4)
    @MaxLength(20)
    @Matches(/((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$/, {message: 'password too weak'})
    password: string;

    @IsString()
    @MinLength(4)
    @MaxLength(20)
    @Validate(CustomMatchPasswords, ['password'])
    passwordConfirm: string;
```

Answer (score 1):

Typescript version: Fixed some lint complains

```js
import {
  ValidatorConstraint,
  ValidatorConstraintInterface,
  ValidationOptions,
  registerDecorator,
  ValidationArguments
} from 'class-validator'
import { ClassConstructor } from 'class-transformer'

type Tfn<T> = (o: T) => any

export const Match = <T>(
  type: ClassConstructor<T>,
  property: Tfn<T>,
  validationOptions?: ValidationOptions
) => {
  return (object: unknown, propertyName: string) => {
    registerDecorator({
      target: object.constructor,
      propertyName,
      options: validationOptions,
      constraints: [property],
      validator: MatchConstraint<T>
    })
  }
}

@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'Match' })
export class MatchConstraint<T> implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  validate(value: any, args: ValidationArguments) {
    const [fn] = args.constraints as Tfn<T>[]
    return fn(args.object as T) === value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@MinLength(requiredlength ex: 5)
 @MaxLength(requiredlength ex:5)
```

are working in latest version so to validate length we can use that.

Comment: What is `requiredlength ex:5`?

Answer (score 0):

Same as [@jrrodasm's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69108578/23109300) suggestion, but I modified it a little like the `@nestjs/mapped-types` concept.

```js
import { Type } from "@nestjs/common";
import { ValidationArguments, ValidationOptions, registerDecorator } from "class-validator";

export function IsMatchWith<T, K extends keyof T>(classRef: Type<T>, property?: readonly K[], validationOpt?: ValidationOptions) {
    return (obj: any, propertyName: string) => {
        registerDecorator({
            target: obj.constructor,
            propertyName,
            options: validationOpt,
            constraints: [property],
            validator: {
                validate(value: any, args: ValidationArguments) {
                    return !(value !== (args.object as any)[args.constraints[0]])
                },

                defaultMessage({ property, constraints }: ValidationArguments): string {
                    return `${property} must match ${constraints[0]}`;
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, previous answers feel like over-engineering. You can do something simple as:

```js
import {
  IsDefined,
  IsIn,
  IsString,
  MinLength,
  ValidateIf,
} from 'class-validator';

export class ForgotReturnPasswordDto {
  @IsString()
  @IsDefined()
  @MinLength(3)
  password: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsDefined()
  @IsIn([Math.random()], {
    message: 'Passwords do not match',
  })
  @ValidateIf((o) => o.password !== o.repeatPassword)
  repeatPassword: string;
}
```