# How do you compare fields in an input type in type graphql using class validator decorators

Tags: typescript, graphql, typeorm, class-validator, typegraphql

I have this example input type:

```
@InputType() 

class ExampleInputType {

@Field(() => Number)
@IsInt()
fromAge: number

@Field(() => Number)
@IsInt()
toAge: number

}
```

Is there a way to compare the `toAge` and `fromAge` fields in this example, using decorators from a validator like `class-validator`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can handle that with a custom validator.
This is a link that is about comparing password and password confirmation.
You can change that for your comparing validator.

[Password confirmation in TypeScript with `class-validator`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60451337/password-confirmation-in-typescript-with-class-validator)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but here is how you can achieve the goal with a custom validator.

```
import {
  ValidationOptions,
  registerDecorator,
  ValidationArguments
} from 'class-validator';

class GenericModel {}

/**
 * A customizable custom validator
 */
export const createCustomValidator = <Model extends GenericModel>(
  validatorName: string,
  validatorFunc: (a: unknown, b: unknown) => boolean,
  modelTypeGuard: (obj: unknown) => obj is Model
) => {
  return (
    otherPropertyName: keyof Model,
    validationOptions?: ValidationOptions
  ) => {
    return (obj: Model, propertyName: string) => {
      registerDecorator({
        name: validatorName,
        target: obj.constructor,
        propertyName,
        constraints: [otherPropertyName],
        options: validationOptions,
        validator: {
          validate(value: string, args: ValidationArguments) {
            const model = args.object;
            if (!modelTypeGuard(model)) {
              return false;
            }

            return validatorFunc(value, model[otherPropertyName]);
          }
        }
      });
    };
  };
};
```

Example usage:

```
const isLessThanOrEqualTo = (a: unknown, b: unknown): boolean => {
  if (typeof a !== 'number' || typeof b !== 'number') {
    return false;
  }

  return a <= b;
};

const isSomeModel = (obj: unknown): obj is SomeModel => {
  return obj instanceof SomeModel;
};

/**
 * __Is Less Than Or Equal To__ validator
 */
const IsLte = createCustomValidator<SomeModel>(
  'isLte',
  isLessThanOrEqualTo,
  isSomeModel
);

export class SomeModel {
  @IsNumber()
  @Min(1, { message: 'minimum points should be positive nonzero number' })
  totalPoints!: number;

  @IsNumber()
  @Min(1, { message: 'minimum points should be positive nonzero number' })
  @IsLte('totalPoints', {
    message: 'Obtained points must be less than or equal to total points'
  })
  obtainedPoints!: number;
}
```

And here is a simple test to validate:

```
  import 'reflect-metadata';
  import { validate, ValidationError } from 'class-validator';

  describe('obtainedPoints', () => {
    it('should throw error when the obtainedPoints is greater than total points', async () => {
      const model = new SomeModel();

      model.totalPoints = 10;
      model.obtainedPoints = 20;

      const result = await validate(model, {
         forbidUnknownValues: true
      });

      expect(result.length).toBe(1);
      expect(result[0].property).toBe('obtainedPoints');
      expect(result[0].constraints?.isLte).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid max you can get is conditional validation:

https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#conditional-validation